# Get a job by contributing to community with Open-source projects as a programmer

Tags: software-industry, job-search, software-development, software

Since I can't really afford programming academies and similar educational programmes and systems, I was wondering if I could find a job by applying somewhere later with decent knowledge in several linked programming languages, like JAVA/Python/PHP/SQL/C, so I could instead of finished certain course or educational programme with an accolade present recent projects I've finished.

Do IT companies hire employees with 'just knowledge'? Do they ask for diplomas and other certificates?

I am just saying this because I am learning Java for very short time, but have experience in some scripting languages that have very similar syntax to C's syntax, as well as SQL databases, etc.

Comment: Related: [How to explain why I don't have a degree](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/12879). [Lack of university degree](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/80038). [How limiting is my lack of a bachelor's degree for my career in web development?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/11986) [How to explain that my experience makes up for my lack of qualifications?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/21057)

Comment: See also: [Are side projects acceptable "work experience" for an entry level worker?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1272)

Comment: java isn't a scripting language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do IT companies hire employees with 'just knowledge'? Do they ask for diplomas and other certificates?

Yes to both.

A lot depends on the human resource pool in a locale. In many places totally unqualified, unsuitable and in other places unemployable people have gotten high paying jobs because there is no other choices.

One interview for a sysadmin position I was part of had 2 candidates.

A theological student who said he didn't really know much but was a fast learner and God would help him focus.

And a young man who had done 2/3'rds of a CCNA

The young man got the job, and he was replacing a chap who is now in prison for fraud, who landed the job by lying and obtaining a false police record report.

Comment: Just curious, which one got the job?

Comment: @solarflare The young guy, and he's turned out to be very committed, intelligent and trainable, we really lucked out.

Comment: Guess we'll never know.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply for any jobs you want.

Will you get them? That's not a question this community can answer. *"Do IT companies hire employees based on knowledge without degrees, diplomas or certifications?"*

**Yes**, but not frequently.

You should create a resume that demonstrates why your work on specific projects meets the kinds of criteria hiring managers are looking for when it comes to technical *and* soft skills. You should also do informational interviews with hiring managers at companies you might be interested in working for in order to find out what, exactly, they're looking for in an employee and ask whether or not they have hired someone with your (lack of) formal education. If they have, find out what made those candidates stand out and seem worth taking a chance on.

Comment: The main point here is "not frequently". For someone as the OP that is akin to "I make a career in music as successfull pop star" - while most musicians starve. Not realistic.

Comment: As a software engineer, the **single most** important thing I have found is *experience*, not a piece of paper.